# Titanium Studio: How can i add a widget to my view with javascript

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

In a **Classic** Titanium project if i want to create a button i use this code ↓

```
var btn = Ti.UI.createButton();
```

How can i do the same for an **Alloy** project using js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question title is different from the description.

To add a widget to Alloy project use this code in the xml file:

```
<Widget src="widgetName" id="myWidget" />
```

And to create a button in xml file:

```
<Button id="btn" class="btn">My Button</Button
```

To Access the widget or the button from the js file, use the `$` that access the controller and then the id you assigned to them:

```
$.btn.backgroundColor = "red";
$.myWidget.initialize(fooParameter);
```

If you need to create a button in the js file, use the same code you mentioned and add the created button to the opened window:

```
var btn = Ti.UI.createButton({ title: 'My Button' });
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({ backgroundColor: 'white' });
win.add(btn); // If you created the window in the xml file --> $.win.add(btn);
win.open();
```

Click the next links for [Buttons](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button) and [Widgets](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Widgets) documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium docs is best place to find the answer of this, Please refer [Ti.UI.Button](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Button)